# Show that some function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

My request is  to prove that the  function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}-
 \frac{1}{e^x-1} & if & x\neq 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & if & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
is differentiable at $x=0$. I already  show that it is continuous at $x=0$ by using the L'Hopital rule twice. But in differentiability I failed to achieve this despite using L'Hopital rule.

Any help is welcome

Comment: you might like to include your attempt in your post. rather than just describing it.

Answer (score 0):

you must compute the term $$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{\frac{1}{h}-\frac{1}{e^h-1}-\frac{1}{2}}{h}$$ for $$h\neq 0$$ and then compute the limit for $h$ tends to zero
this can be simplified to $$\frac{2-h\coth\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)}{2h^2}$$
for your control, the searched limit is $$-\frac{1}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

For small $x$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{e^x-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+x^2/2+x^3/6+O(x^4)}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}(1-\frac{1}{1+x/2+x^2/6+O(x^3)})\\
&=\frac{1}{x}(1-(1-(x/2+x^2/6+O(x^3))+(x/2+x^2/6+O(x^3))^2+O(x^3))\\
&=\frac{1}{x}(x/2+x^2/6+O(x^3)-(x^2/4)(1+x/3+O(x^2))^2+O(x^3))\\
&=\frac{1}{x}(x/2+x^2/6+O(x^3)-(x^2/4)(1+2x/3+O(x^2))+O(x^3))\\
&=\frac{1}{x}(x/2-x^2/12+O(x^3))\\
&=\frac12-x/12+O(x^2)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f'(x)
=-\frac1{12}+O(x)
$.

(added later)

According to Wolfy
$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{e^x-1}
=1/2 - x/12 + x^3/720 + O(x^4)
$.